# Deploy Nodejs app with local dependencies to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

How can I deploy NodeJS app with local dependencies to GAE???

My app has local dependencies in package.json, so it failed.

Thanks!

Comment: You should add an answer to your question with the solution - to not leave the question appear as unanswered

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that

Comment: No problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No help came so I did it myself. Here's the solution for everyone has the same problem. Use `gulp` to copy local resources into current directory.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');
const del = require('del');
const fs = require('fs');
const resolve = require('path').resolve;

let getPackageGlobs = (dir) => {
  let paths = [
    dir + '/**',
    '!' + dir + '/node_modules/**',
    '!' + dir + '/npm-debug.log',
    '!' + dir + '/build',
  ];

  try {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(dir + '/.npmignore', {
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    });

    paths = paths.concat(data.split("\n")
      .filter((e) => e.length > 0)
      .map((e) => dir + '/' + e)
      .filter(fs.existsSync)
      .map((e) => fs.lstatSync(e).isDirectory() ? '!' + e + '/**' : '!' + e));
  } catch (err) { }

  return paths;
};

gulp.task('build.clean', () => {
  return del(__dirname + '/build');
});

gulp.task('build.copy', () => {
  return gulp.src(getPackageGlobs(__dirname))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.task('build.normalize', () => {
  let packageJson = require('./build/package.json');
  let tasks = [];

  for (let name in packageJson.dependencies) {
    for (let s of ['../', '~/', './', '/']) {
      if (packageJson.dependencies[name].startsWith(s)) {
        tasks.push(gulp
        .src(getPackageGlobs(resolve(packageJson.dependencies[name])))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/local_modules/' + name)));

        packageJson.dependencies[name] = './local_modules' + '/' + name;

        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile('./build/package.json',
      JSON.stringify(packageJson), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(merge(tasks));
        }
      });
  });
});

gulp.task('build', (done) => {
  runSequence('build.clean',
    'build.copy',
    'build.normalize',
    done);
});
```

And run with `gulp build && gcloud app deploy build/app.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Hung Hoang for the question and their answer. Their answer solved my issue as well. I was motivated to write a solution that achieves the same result (and a few improvements) without using Gulp.

The following code assumes that you have a local package located at `../local`, and that the current working directory contains the Node.js application and the `package.json` to be deployed to App Engine.

The overall idea is to copy the contents of `../local` to the Node.js app directory before deploying. This way, the local package code will be included as part of the code uploaded as part of the deploy, and the deploy will not result in an error. But, additionally, for this to work correctly the `package.json` dependency entry for the `../local` package also needs to be updated.

There are three steps to the process (defined in Makefile format).

```
deploy: _predeploy _deploy _postdeploy
```

The pre-deploy step prepares files for deployment. See inline comments for details.

```sh
_predeploy:
    # copy package to current directory
    cp -r ../local tmp-local
    # preserve original package.json,package-lock.json
    cp package.json package.json.original
    cp package-lock.json package-lock.json.original
    # rewrite local dependency value in package.json (../local -> ./tmp-local)
    sed -i '' 's/file:\.\.\/local/file:.\/tmp-local/g' package.json
    # update package-lock.json corresondingly
    npm i --package-lock-only
```

The deploy step does the actual deploy using the `gcloud` command.

```
_deploy:
    gcloud app deploy
```

Finally the post-deploy step cleans up files created during the pre-deploy step, and restores the original state of `package.json` (such that `../local` can be used as usual for local development).

```sh
_postdeploy:
    # undo package.json,package-lock.json changes
    mv package.json.original package.json
    mv package-lock.json.original package-lock.json
    # remove copied package
    rm -rf tmp-local
```

To run, execute `make deploy`.